# Можно ли создать консольное приложение по типу create-react-app на node?

Tags: node.js

У меня давно зреет мысль создать что-то наподобие create-react-app, я использую некоторые нестандартные настройки и не очень-то удобно с каждым проектом их подключать. Хочу создать команду, с помощью которой будет создаваться каркас проекта, подключаться все необходимые мне модули и создаваться определенные готовые файлы.

Т.е. я хочу именно, писать в консоль в заданной директории к примеру `create-my-app name-app` и чтобы там создавался проект. Я могу создать команду типа `node create.js name-app PATH`, которая будет работать в определенной директории, но мне интересно сделать именно как написал в первом предложении.

Можно ли это сделать с помощью node.js и как это сделать? Буду очень признателен за подсказку, статью, а то не могу ничего внятного найти. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы можете сделать .bat файл, который будет называться `create-my-app.bat`. (Из консоли бат-файлы можно запускать без указания расширения). В самом батнике пишите команды, которые необходимо выполнить (запустить скрипт на ноде, к примеру). Кстати, батники тоже умеют принимать аргументы, вы можете в самом батнике их принять и перенаправить в ноду. В общем, гугл в помощь. (Сейчас добавлю ответом пример)

Comment: Может создать один раз каркас, после залить его например на гит, и потом с помощью гита делать в указанную папку клон, и работать с ним.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как вариант - создать `.bat`-файл.**

Батники из командной строки можно запускать без указания расширения, а также они умеют принимать аргументы. К примеру (батник):

```
:: create-my-app.bat:

@echo off 
node create-my-app.js %1 %2
```

Скрипт:

```
// create-my-app.js:

console.log("First parameter: "+ process.argv[2], "Second parameter: " + process.argv[3]);
```

Открываете консоль в папке с этими двумя файлами, выполняете:

```
create-my-app foldername anotherparameter
```

На выходе получаете:

```
First parameter: foldername Second parameter: anotherparameter
```

Заметьте: нулевой параметр будет указывать на расположение `node.exe`, а первый - на ваш `create-my-app.js`. Начиная с индекса `2` будут идти параметры, переданные вами.

Answer (score 1):

Прошло много времени но все же обновлю инфу! на VSCODE есть модуль который создает шаблоны. и их можно создавать в пару кликов. один раз написали шаблон и пользуйтесь сколько угодно... причем он поддерживает переменные которые вы определяете в коде шаблона и при создании указываете на них данные. К примеру название проекта, версию, автора и любые другие данные. Вот ссылка на этот проект: https://github.com/cantonios/vscode-project-templates